# Prove that R is anti-symmetric

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $R$ be a relation on $P(\mathbb{N}) $ with  $(A,B) \in R$ if and only if

for all $a \in A$ there is a $b \in B $ with $a\leq b$

Prove that R is anti-symmetric

I tried to prove that if $(A,B) \in R$ and $ A \neq B$ than $(B,A) \notin R$ but didn't succeed.

I tried to find the difference between a set that is equal and a set that is not equal in terms of b and a so that I can say that there is a b that is greater than all the a

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Do you know what an anti-symmetric relation is?

Comment: What you need to show is either that if $(A,B)$ and $(B,A)$ in $R$ then $A=B$; or that if $(A,B)\in R$ and $A\neq B$ then $(B,A)\notin R$. Also, "didn't succeed" doesn't tell us anything. How did you try, and where did you get stick and why?

Comment: @lulu a relation that when $(x,y) \in R$ and $(y,x) \in R$ than $x = y$ i think

Comment: "then", not "than".

Comment: Yes, but that's not the test you applied.  It is perfectly possible that *neither* $(A,B)$ nor $(B,A)$ be in $R$.

Comment: Should say:  your quantifiers are unclear.  Say $A$ is the set of even natural numbers, and $B$ the set of odd natural numbers.  Do we have $(A,B)\in R$?  What about $(B,A)$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I tried to find the difference between a set that is equal and a set that is not equal in terms of b and a so that I can say that there is a b that is greater than all the a

Comment: Put the information in the post, for everyone, not buried in comments.

Comment: @lulu but if I say if $(A,B) \in R$ and $A \neq B$ then $(B,A) \notin R$ wouldn't that be enough if i can prove that $R$ is symmetric

Comment: @lulu proving that for all $x,y$, if $x\neq y$ and $(x,y)\in R$ then $(y,x)\notin R$ is a correct way to prove antisymmetry.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin  Absolutely, my error.

Comment: @Michielvaganee  Absolutely, yes.  My error. Sorry about that.

Comment: @lulu no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the reason you are having difficulty proving that the relation is antisymmetric is that the relation is *not* antisymmetric.

For example, let $A=\{1,3\}$, $B=\{2,3\}$. I claim that $(A,B),(B,A)\in R$.

Indeed, note that for each $a\in A$, we have $a\leq 3\in B$. Thus, $(A,B)\in R$. Similarly, for each $b\in B$, we have $b\leq 3\in A$. Thus, $(B,A)\in R$.

So $(A,B),(B,A)\in R$, but $A\neq B$. So $R$ is not anti-symmetric.

The empty set is related to everything in $R$, but no element of $P(\mathbb{N})$ is related to the empty set. $(A,B)\in R$ for $A\neq\varnothing$, $B\neq \varnothing$ if and only if $\sup(A)\leq \sup(B)$ (allowing $\infty$ for the supremum). In particular, note that any set is related to any infinite subset, and so any two infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ are related to one another. It cannot possibly be anti-symmetric.